# Storing / Logging keystrokes in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database-schema, keystroke

I am developing a module which has to log and later playback all individual keystrokes in a form field. I would like to be able to store this in a database, and be able to retrieve this fast.

Typically it will be used to replay the path the user took to come to the finally submitted text.

I want to know if inserting a record for each keypress (perhaps grouping consecutive same strokes with a count for compression , albeit losing some timestamp info ?) is good,

```
CREATE TABLE `keystroke_log` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `keystroke` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `count` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'form_field_id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'timestamp' timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or is it better to store all keystrokes in a single row as serialised JSON object with something like this ?

```
CREATE TABLE `keystroke_log` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `form_field_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `keystroke_dump` MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**EDIT**: The `keystroke_dump` JSON object would ideally contain timestamp and the actual UTF-8 stroke code

Is there any better way to store and retrieve this data ?

JSON in a relational DB is never a good idea, however the most common query will have to load the entire object anyway querying for full playback I am not sure if using a sql structure will result in significant performance loss?

Comment: are you trying to capture my home banking password? :-) I'd go with the second option. Storing each keypress + timestamp looks a little "over" for me

Comment: Why would you store JSON object insteaf of a simple utf8 (or whatever) encoded string ?

Comment: The best way to store the data depends on how you plan to use it.

Comment: @Zaffy i am not talking about storing the final string, i am talking about the keystrokes that lead to it,

Comment: @Leo lol!.. this is to monitor students and prevent cheating in assessments :D

Comment: @Manquer I was talking about your second solution.

Comment: @DanBracuk the question mentions that already, the main purpose is to playback the keystrokes

Comment: @Zaffy ah, that is because I would like to also store the timestamp data along with the stroke?

Comment: I suggest storing each keypress and the order in which they were made.  Watch yourself though.  This sentence was added to the comment without any keyboard actions in the form field.  You might want to capture left and right mouse clicks as well.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the tip, i will be mostly disabling context menu pasting and some other mouse actions to handle such events.